# remove_action - pre_get_posts - does not restore original query

Tags: wp-query, ajax, hooks, actions

I have following functions ...

```
function ajax_sortposts() {
    global $wp_query;
    $sorting_order = $_POST['sorting_order'];

    if ( $sorting_order == 'Latest' ) {
        remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'query_get_posts_by_views' );
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    else {
        add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'query_get_posts_by_views' );
    }

    get_content();

    die;
} 

function get_content () {
    global $wp_query;
    wp(); 
?>
    <div id="post-wrapper" class="grid-wrapper">
        <?php
            if ( have_posts() ) :
                echo '<div class="gallery-wrapper">';
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                    if ( 'one-column' === get_option( 'baseline_customizer_post_style', 'one-column' ) ) {
                        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content' );
                    } else {
                        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-grid-item' );
                    }
                endwhile;

                echo '</div>';
            else :
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-none' );
            endif;

            if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 )
                echo '<div class="loadmore_posts">More posts</div>';
        ?>
    </div>
<?php 
}

function query_get_posts_by_views( $query ) {

    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'post');
        $query->set('posts_per_page', get_option('posts_per_page'));
        $query->set('paged', 1);
        $query->set('post_status', 'publish');
        $query->set('ignore_sticky_posts', true);
        $query->set('tag__not_in', array(14)); 
        $query->set('order', 'DESC');
        $query->set('meta_key', 'link_click_counter');
        $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
        $query->set('date_query', 
            [    [
                'column' => 'post_date_gmt',
                'after'  => '130 days ago',
            ]    ] 
        );

        return ($query);
    }
}
```

On click I want to change order of posts on home page by number of post views or return order to default.
It is all working fine except remove_action ('pre_get_posts' does not return to original query (it duplicates some posts).
What am I doing wrong?

Ajax function:

```
    jQuery( document ).on( 'click', '[class*=sortingMenu]', function() {
  var sorting_order = jQuery(this).attr('sorting_order');
  jQuery.ajax({
    url : ajaxposts.ajax_posts_url,
    type : 'post',
    data : {
        action : 'sortposts',
        sorting_order : sorting_order
    },
    beforeSend:function( xhr ){
        document.getElementById("sortingLoader").style.visibility = "visible";


    },
    success : function( response ) {

        if (sorting_order == "Latest") {
            document.getElementById("Latest").classList.add('selectedSort');
            document.getElementById("MostViewed").classList.remove('selectedSort');
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("MostViewed").classList.add('selectedSort');
            document.getElementById("Latest").classList.remove('selectedSort');
        }           

        jQuery('#post-wrapper').remove();
        jQuery('.pagination').remove();
        jQuery('#main').append(response);
        loadmore_posts_params.current_page = 1;

        // Fade in the images as they load
        function fade_images() {
        $('.gallery-wrapper .gallery-thumb').each(function(i) {
            var row = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() {
                row.addClass('fadeInUp');
            }, 90*i)
        });
        }

        // Masonry blocks
        var $blocks = $('.two-column .gallery-wrapper,.three-column .gallery-wrapper');

        $blocks.imagesLoaded( function() {
            $blocks.masonry({
            itemSelector: 'body:not(.one-column) .post',
            transitionDuration: 0
        });

        // Fade blocks in after images are ready
        fade_images();
        });

        document.getElementById("sortingLoader").style.visibility = "hidden";
    },
    error: function () {
        document.getElementById("sortingLoader").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }     
});

return false;

})
```

Here are the options link:

```
   function sorting_menu() { ?>

    href="javascript:void(0)" sorting_order="Latest" id="Latest" class="sortingMenu selectedSort">Latest</a>
    &ensp;
    href="javascript:void(0)" sorting_order="MostViewed" id="MostViewed" class="sortingMenu">Most viewed</a>


  }
```

Comment: And what do you do with the result of that AJAX function? Do you add that action anywhere else in your code? And where does the global `$wp_query` comes from in an AJAX call? How do you set it?

Comment: @Krzysiek, I have added ajax function code in question above.

Comment: OK, so I have no idea how your code does anything - it's some magic, that it even works right now ;) Let me prepare the answer

Comment: Options links included. Is that what you mean? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so first of all - AJAX requests are separate, so you don't have to `remove_action` if you haven't added it earlier...

And to be honest, I don't really get your code - you modify the global `wp_query` object, but it's really not so clear how and why is there any query created during AJAX call - WP processes these requests in a different way... Saying this, here's the code that should work... (it doesn't need any changes in your JS, so I'm posting only PHP code)

```
function ajax_sortposts() {
    $sorting_order = $_POST['sorting_order'];

    // we don't use any global $wp_query, since no global $wp_query is created during AJAX calls
    // instead we create our own WP_Query instance - so we don't need to use pre_get_posts
    $posts_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page', get_option('posts_per_page'),
        'paged' => 1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
        'tag__not_in' => array(14),
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'date_query' => array(
            array(
                'column' => 'post_date_gmt',
                'after'  => '130 days ago',
            )
        )
    ) );
    if ( 'MostViewed' == $sorting_order ) {
        $posts_query['meta_key'] = 'link_click_counter';
        $posts_query['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
    }

    get_content( $posts_query );

    die;
} 

function get_content ( $query ) {
    // again we shouldn't use global $wp_query in here
    // and certainly we SHOULDN'T call wp() function at all...
?>
    <div id="post-wrapper" class="grid-wrapper">
        <?php
            if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
                echo '<div class="gallery-wrapper">';
                while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                    if ( 'one-column' === get_option( 'baseline_customizer_post_style', 'one-column' ) ) {
                        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content' );
                    } else {
                        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-grid-item' );
                    }
                endwhile;

                echo '</div>';
            else :
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-none' );
            endif;

            if (  $query->max_num_pages > 1 )
                echo '<div class="loadmore_posts">More posts</div>';
        ?>
    </div>
<?php 
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you for trying to help. Maybe I wans't clear on my idea. My home page is multi post page, in header of page I have added two links (Latest and Most Viewed). This links call ajax function i .js file. Ajax then calls "ajax_sort_posts" in php wich applies pre_get_posts and returns new content that is refreshed by ajax. This part is working fine. Problem is when I click latest again and want to remove pre_get_posts, my query dosen't return to original state. Hope I was more clear this time.

Comment: I understand what you’re trymiga to achieve, but your code is a mess. You can’t call wp() or hope that WP will magically create global wp_query by itself... AJAX requests are processed in a different way so you should create your own query in you AJAX callback function.

Comment: Ok, I understand. This can't be done this way. I was thinking that I could do it because of problems with pagination if I create separte query.

Comment: @GoranDžepina It dań be done using AJAX and it can be done in a simillar way - just not with your code because it’s a magic that it does anything at all ;) Take a look at my answer - this is the code that will be a good starting point - you can easily fiddle with the query that I’ve put in there...